Как изменить метод реализации CallBack от WCF в приложении WPF
В приложении WPF есть несколько страниц, и каждая по своему должна обрабатывать CallBack от WCF, но при переходе между страницами CallBack приходит в метод с первой странице на которой был вызван
Вот код интерфейса WCF
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IServerChatCallback))]
    public interface IServiceChat
    {
        [OperationContract]
        int Login(string email,string password);          //Вход

        [OperationContract]
        int Register(string name, string email, string password);       //Регистрация

        [OperationContract]
        void Exit();           //Выход

        [OperationContract]
        List<string> GetUsersList(int id);           //Получить список пользователей


        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void SendMessage(string messagetxt,int FromUID,int ToID);  //Отправка сообщения

        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void UpdateUser(List<string> names);  //Обновить список пользователей

    }

    public interface IServerChatCallback
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void MessageCallback(string messagetxt, int FromUID, int ToID); //callback сообщения

        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void LoginCallback(List<string> names); //callback Логирования
    }

